# How to make continuous pull-out items?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make continuous pull-out elements. I seem able to create one just fine, but am having difficulties creating any more than that. The effect I am after is that when you scroll down, item 2 gets revealed from underneath, and then when you keep scrolling, item 3 gets revealed from underneath item 2. I'd like this to keep going for as many items I add.

Here's the first snippet, with 3 items. It is not working properly:

```css
html, body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.text-center{
 text-align: center;
}
#item-1{
 position: relative;
 height: 500px;
 margin-bottom: 500px;
 background-color: white;
 border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}
#item-2{
 background-color: green;
 border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
 z-index: -1;
}
#item-3{
 background: yellow;
 z-index: -1;
}
.slide-item{
 text-align: center;
 height: 500px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="item-1" class="text-center">
  First item!
  <div id="item-2" class="slide-item text-center">
   Second item!
   <div id="item-3" class="slide-item text-center">
    Third item!
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is another snippet, with only two items, which appears to be working, except the text isn't showing up (it shows up fine on my test page, though).

```css
html, body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.text-center{
 text-align: center;
}
#item-1{
 position: relative;
 height: 500px;
 margin-bottom: 500px;
 background-color: white;
 border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
}
#item-2{
 background-color: green;
 border-bottom: 5px solid gray;
 z-index: -1;
}
#item-3{
 background: yellow;
 z-index: -1;
}
.slide-item{
 text-align: center;
 height: 500px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="item-1" class="text-center">
  First item!
  <div id="item-2" class="slide-item text-center">
   Second item!
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you looking [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/22emq8c0/1/ ] like this one ?? it's for the three item

Comment: No, sorry, the items have to pull out from one another. Like this, but with three items rather than just the two. http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2013/08/slideout-footer-css/

Comment: ok got it .. :)

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: Never done this before. but if it works for 2 item then obviously its work for more items. lets try :)

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/knfk1gdj/ ]  the problem is its depends on z-index value and padding top and structure need to be like this..But I'have facing a problem, I set each p.text different color. but only 1 text color gose right others are overlapping each other. I think maybe try with jQuery also